# Django won't display textfield from model

Tags: python, django

I have a login system where you need to be logged in to submit a new post. My "New Post" page/form work fine and the content the user submits is properly posted in the database, how when it comes to displaying that content on the home page only the title and subtitle are shown (which are Charfields) and no the body text of the post (which is a text field).

inde.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}


    <div class="left">
        {% if userposts %}
            {% for posts in userposts %}
                <div class="front-post">
                    <h2 class="post-title">{{ posts.post_title }}</h2>
                    <h3 class="post-sub-title">{{ posts.post_sub_title }}</h3>
                    <p class="post-author">{{ post.post_author }}</p>
                    <p class="post-date">{{ post.post_date }}</p>
                    <p class="post-body">{{ post.post_body }}</p>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>


    <div class="right">
        <p>SIDE BAR</p>
    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog.forms import UserForm,UserProfileInfoForm,AddPost
from blog.models import UserPosts

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    post_list = UserPosts.objects.order_by('post_date')
    post_dict = {'userposts':post_list}

    return render(request, 'blog/index.html',context=post_dict)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank='True')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class UserPosts(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    post_sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=False)
    post_author = ''
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    post_body = models.TextField(max_length=1000,unique=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.post_title)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from blog.models import UserProfileInfo,UserPosts

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password')

class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ('portfolio_site','profile_pic')

class AddPost(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserPosts
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: is it just a typo  ? `posts.post_sub_title` vs `post.post_body`

Comment: Possibly because you typed `post` instead of `posts` in your `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch your naming. Your `for` loop variable is named `posts` (with an `s` at the end) but you're trying to display `post.post_body`. In some places it's working because you're using `posts.post_title`.

To fix this issue, rename `posts` to just `post` everywhere in your for loop.

```
{% for post in userposts %}
  <div class="front-post">
      <h2 class="post-title">{{ post.post_title }}</h2>
      <h3 class="post-sub-title">{{ post.post_sub_title }}</h3>
      <p class="post-author">{{ post.post_author }}</p>
      <p class="post-date">{{ post.post_date }}</p>
      <p class="post-body">{{ post.post_body }}</p>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Django will silently fail any expressions it can't evaluate in the templates, which is why nothing was being shown.